# Как нажать на кнопку, на сайте

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    $("document").ready(function() $(".mm-queue-actions[class='btn btn-sm btn-primary']").click();
    });
})();
```

Код из `Tampermonkey`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Мы говорим `Jquery`: *возьми `div` с классом `mm-queue-actions` а в нём кнопку*.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
   $('document').ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'div.mm-queue-actions > button' ,() => console.log('Click!'));
    $('div.mm-queue-actions > button').click(); 
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="mm-queue-actions">
  <button type="button" class=" btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
</div>
```

> UPD Пример запуска на [github](https://gist.github.com/eristoddle/4440713).

Код для **Tampermonkey**:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://steamcommunity.com/openid/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    document.getElementById('steamAccountName').value='test';
    document.getElementById('steamPassword').value='test';
    document.getElementById('imageLogin').click();
})();
```

*P.S. В вашем коде опечатка (тут: `.ready(function() $(`) вы забыли `{`.*

Comment: не работает, или я рукажоп. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @антонЛеонов Подправил. `$('div.mm-queue-actions > button').on('click', () => console.log('Click!'));` Для наглядности, чтобы вы видели, что сработал клик. Если я ответил на ваш вопрос — примите его. Удачи.

Comment: мне кажется дело в том, что кнопка появляется после обновление страницы и из за этого скрипт не видит его. Что то можно изменить ?

Comment: @антонЛеонов обновил. И скрипты переместите перед `</body>`. Скорее всего этот `html` код приходит после запроса сервера. Вставьте `$('div.mm-queue-actions > button').click();` в `callback`.

Comment: либо я не то делаю, но я скрипт в Tampermonkey вписываю.

Comment: @антонЛеонов обновил ответ, проверьте.

Comment: проверил, не работает

Comment: @антонЛеонов А остальные скрипты у вас работают?

Comment: да, могу скрин скинуть

Comment: @антонЛеонов В аопрос добавьте и если можно сайт на котором не работает.

Comment: вот сайт, https://scrap.tf/sell/cards

Comment: Здравствуйте. вы можете помочь ?

Comment: @антонЛеонов готово. Работает. Проверял.

Comment: вы написали в @match        https://steamcommunity.com/openid/
а нужно же на сайте (*https://scrap.tf/*), или я не правильно делаю.

Comment: @антонЛеонов так он редиректит туда.